# What are the advantages / disadvantages of building in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I work at a more traditional ad agency and I am the sole web guy here. Recently a designer here redesigned our website based on the popular blog style seen about on the internets at the moment. Design is similar to this blog: http://effektiveblog.com/

I put forward that this would be a WordPress job, due to the designed features (tag cloud, dated/categorized posts, ability to be updated, rss, etc)

However, the non-web people at my workplace are saying they don't want to "do WordPress" and are planning on out-sourcing a custom CMS for this blog-look-a-like site!

As you can imagine, this is very frustrating and back-to-front.

However, as I haven't really delved fully into WordPress enough I don't fully know what arguments to put forward in regards to advantages/disadvantages in building it with WordPress vs a custom CMS.

Any thoughts on what to suggest to non-web superiors? or links even pointing to similar discussions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been in the WordPress world for a few years and my observations have been that most of the "WordPress vs. other CMS" arguments boil down to a couple things:

- Ultimately, you *could* use WordPress for nearly any CMS task, and you *could* use a general CMS to build blog content
- WordPress was designed primarily as a blogging platform, so that's where it really shines.  Yes, it can be used for other CMS tasks, but it does blogging best and that's where you'll find the most support and robust features.
- More general CMS systems will offer features designed for a variety of content (not just blog posts or static pages), but they won't offer as many features (or as easy of an experience) for the blogging component as WordPress will.

Generally I tell folks that if the focus of the site is frequently updated content that is managed in a chronological fashion (like a blog), go with WordPress.  If they're looking to integrate a bunch of disparate content and blogging isn't really important, they'll probably be better served by a more general CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is great for blogs and mid size simple websites. It's "static pages" approach is **really** useful, because you can create hirarchies that are fully editable from admin panel. It's plugin ecosystem is **very** good also - from SEO to automatic backups.

When I needed to convince some people that Wordpress would be a good idea to a CMS solution (not just a blog one), I created a prototype, and said that I just needed to edit a few php files (all copied from the default template), a few administration tasks and a few plugins and I was all set.

This prototype was really simple: no design, just structure. I made it in a saturday afternoon, and I made a challenge to everyone involved if they could create the same structure I created, with a full admin interface, in less time. No one could. And it's a tested plataform, yes, it's not "all MVC based", but it works and its administration is great to use.

I don't know if you have time to do it, but since is really fast to do it, I'd rather show them instead of just saying it.

One disadvantage of Wordpress is its performance. You may need to look at some cache plugins for your installation, like WpSuperCache. And be warned that if your website, in a long run, is going to have a lot of different requirements, Wordpress may not be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

**WordPress** is definitely the world's most popular CMS. The script is in its roots more of a blog than a typical CMS. For a while now it's been modernized and it got thousands of plugins, what made it more CMS-like.

**Advantages** -

- **Easy to operate**-

  WordPress does not require PHP nor HTML knowledge unlinke Drupal, Joomla or Typo3. A preinstalled plugin and template function allows them to be installed very easily. All you need to do is to choose a plugin or a template and click on it to install. 
  It's good choice for beginners.
- **Community**-

  To have a useful support, there must be a large community of users, who will be a part of e.g. a discussion board.
- **Plugins**-

  The script has over dozen thousand of plugins available on its website. They are the reason WordPress is considered a CMS, not only a blogging script. Strong majority of the plugins is available for free.
- **Templates**-

  On the scritp's homepage you can view thousands of graphics templates, that can change your website's look. You can find there both free and paid templates. The paid ones are often more advanced as well as more interesting.
- **Menu management**-

  WordPress menu management has extended functionalities, that can be modified to include categories, pages, etc.
- **E-commerce is available on WordPress**

  At Designed to Connect, we generally use Woocommerce – an e-commerce add on to WordPress to build our e-commerce websites.  As an e-commerce store, you will often find yourself updating your products, pricing, sales, coupons and more.  Woocommerce is extremely effective in doing all this along with offering great reports features.

**Disadvantages** -

- **WordPress updates their software frequently**-

  WordPress is constantly changing and growing and it needs regular updates. This is not a big deal unless you are looking for a set-it-and-forget-it solution, in which case this might not be the solution for you as it needs periodic updates.
- **Customization of a theme can be costly**-

  If the website was built upon a theme and you decide that you want to make major changes to it, it may be time-consuming to have a programmer make changes to the layout of the theme. If you anticipate needing to make major changes to the theme, consider having a theme built from scratch to meet your needs instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages**:

1. Low cost to upkeep / maintain website is cheap
2. Easy and good with usability on back-end
3. Tons of plugins (which can slow your site down significantly)
4. Write your own functions if you know PHP.
5. codex.wordpress.org, the documentation is so easy
6. Tons of updates for security
7. The community, the millions of users
8. SEO possibilities (when compared to other famous CMS)
9. Can make a big corporate to small website

**Disadvantages**:

1. Not the the most optimum use of its resources (but its getting better every update)
2. Security (also improving)

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages**:

1. Simple
2. Huge number of themes and plugins
3. SEO
4. Easily convert site to Ecommerce

**Disadvantages**

1. Customization

Source: [Advantages and disadvantages of wordpress](http://www.blogginguru.com/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-wordpress/)